# IBM Watson Assistant call to IBM Cloud Function - Runtime error

Tags: function, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant, watson-discovery

I am trying to query an IBM Watson [Discovery Collection (enriched webcrawl)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIWoe.jpg) through a Watson Assistant Chatbot using an IBM Cloud Function. I followed the instructions in this post [IBM Cloud functions to call Watson services](https://github.com/rodalton/watson-functions) - thank you very much Rodalton, this was a great help.

However, I am receiving runtime errors when I try to call the cloud function from the Watson Assistant node. The error message is: **Proyx error: Content-type can not be retrieved**.
The Assistant node has the following code and looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxYsb.jpg) (the JSON below is entered in the JSON editor that opens when you click on the gear icon highlighted in yellow).

```
    {
  "output": {
    "text": {
      "values": [],
      "selection_policy": "sequential"
    },
    "generic": []
  },
  "actions": [
    {
      "name": "/*****@*****.***_dev/actions/*******",
      "type": "server",
      "parameters": {
        "input": "<?input.text?>"
      },
      "credentials": "$my_creds",
      "result_variable": "context.discovery_output"
    }
  ]
}
```

Below is the cloud function and I have entered all parameters [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXxpJ.jpg):

```
    /**
  *
  * @param {object} params
  * @param {string} params.iam_apikey
  * @param {string} params.url
  * @param {string} params.username
  * @param {string} params.password
  * @param {string} params.environment_id
  * @param {string} params.collection_id
  * @param {string} params.configuration_id
  * @param {string} params.input
  *
  * @return {object}
  *
  */

const assert = require('assert');
const DiscoveryV1 = require('watson-developer-cloud/discovery/v1');

function main(params) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

      let discovery;

      if (params.iam_apikey){
        discovery = new DiscoveryV1({
          'iam_apikey': params.iam_apikey,
          'url': params.url,
          'version': '2018-12-03'
        });
      }
      else {
        discovery = new DiscoveryV1({
          'username': params.username,
          'password': params.password,
          'url': params.url,
          'version': '2018-12-03'
      });
    }

    discovery.query({
      'environment_id': params.environment_id,
      'collection_id': params.collection_id,
      'configuration_id': params.configuration_id,
      'natural_language_query': params.input,
      'passages': false,
      'return': 'text'
    }, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      return resolve(data);
    });
  });
}
```

- The endpoint is from [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yVVF.jpg). If I append a '.json' to my endpoint I
  get the error 'Webhook call response body exceeds 1050000 byte
  limit...'
- My Namespace Settings (username:password) are from
  [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbsVk.jpg).
- After providing a user input in the Try Out Panel of the Assistant that hits the Discovery node and jumps to the Discovery_results child node as intended, the Context variable '$results_variable' is 'null' as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iS5VE.jpg). However, when I invoke the action on this page cloud.ibm.com/functions/details/action/*****%2540****.com_dev//*******/code I am getting the results [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8I4hF.jpg). However, it takes about 12 seconds until I see the results on the right.

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: The function code should not be called anymore. The recommended way since over a year is to use webhooks: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-webhooks The following tutorial makes use of them and calls into a Cloud Function: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/tutorials/slack-chatbot-database-watson.html#build-a-database-driven-slackbot

Comment: Thank you very much data_henrik. I followed the instructions and think I got it working now. However, I am getting errors (401/ 403) when I try to call the discovery collection function through the Assistant node.

Comment: Have you enabled security and are not passing credentials?

Comment: I am passing the credentials in the URL for testing in my cloud function which I query by webhook in my assistant. I guess this is not the best way to do this but it works.

Comment: I asked about credentials because 403 is an authorization issue